# Svg how to position elements lo left and right like with floats?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm building a organizational chart with the help of dagre-d3,js and d3.js.

Its svg based so every person in the chart needs to have some kind of a employee card (or call it profile card)

This card needs to show the Persons name, his group and have 2 buttons, one for deleting and for just some popup modal data.

So this is what i would like it to be structured:

[image]

Basic stuff, right?

So how can style and create this with svg?

This is what i have now:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(307.828125,163.5)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <rect rx="0" ry="0" x="-79.5" y="-29.5" width="159" height="59"></rect>
    <g class="label" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <g transform="translate(-49.5, -8)">
            <g class="employee-card">
                <text dx="-15" y="4" class="title">
                    <tspan dx="-15" class="person-name">Bakos Róbert</tspan>
                    <tspan x="-15" dy="22" class="le-name">Delphi fejlesztő</tspan>
                </text>
                <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/media/images/hierarchy/delete.png" width="16" height="16"></image>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

And its not good because for the the buttons i want to use images but i cant seem to figure out how to aling the image (btn) to the top right corner, because these card can be longer or shorter so their sizes are static?

Comment: Have you tried to do this using CSS? going like g.employee-card img {position: } etc? Also, are you calculating the translation for the group above employee card dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG doesn't have automatic layout like HTML.

You have to position the `<image>` yourself where you want it.  To do that just add `x` and `y` attributes to your `<image>`.